# LwM2M specification for multiple clients

Tags: iot, lwm2m

We are reading the LwM2M 2m spec for a college assignment simulation and trying to implement client and server requests.

Finding it hard to understand few details. Documentation is limited on it. We were told a requirement was to configure multiple clients. Does that mean each end point will have its own object ids according to LwM2M? What will be unique for each client? What we understood was each client has several objects like location, device, access control, security etc. Is there any good documentation out there or can someone give us a pointer for basic hierarchy of LwM2M?

Answer (score 0):

LwM2M server registers client devices by uniqued endpoint name. To understand the lwm2m server and client flow better, you should play this demo sand box from leshan lwm2m

https://leshan.eclipseprojects.io/#/clients

You can read this to understand more about API in lwM2M

https://www.win.tue.nl/~lrahman/iot_2016/tutorial/LeshanTutorial_2016_v2.pdf